# Getting a NoMethodError when trying to write to SQLite database

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm working with Sinatra to create a method to get data from a line separated text file and store them in a SQLite database. I'm using DataMapper to create my class, which looks as follows:

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'


DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")

class Names
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :value1, Integer
  property :value2, Integer
  property :value3, Integer
  property :value4, Integer
  property :value5, Integer
  property :value6, Integer
  property :value7, Integer
  property :value8, Integer
  property :value9, Integer
  property :value10, Integer
  property :value11, Integer
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

In my app.rb I am running the following code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require './Names'
require 'rubygems'
require 'data_mapper'
 # persist the resource

get '/' do
  File.foreach("names-data.txt").each do |line|
    name, *values = line.split
    params = {:name => name}
    values.each_with_index do |value, i|
      params[:"value#{i+1}"] = value
    end
    my_data = Names.new params
    my_data.save
  end
end
```

The text files are in the following format:

```
Cat 3 24 2 2 4 6 4 7 6 0 0
Dog 18 0 8 2 42 6 6 4 5 8 0 
Mouse 8 1 2 2 4 6 4 7 6 0 0
Rabbit 8 10 8 26 46 2 6 7 6 10 0
```

When I run my code, it creates a database with the proper columns, but does not populate the rows. Instead, it gives me the following error:

> NoMethodError at / undefined method `validators' for Names:Class Did
>   you mean? validatable?

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: In what line is that error raised? Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: +1, please show the complete error log. Is the first script you show called `Names.rb`? Ruby filenames are usually written in lowercase. `require './Names'` probably should be the last require, after 'rubygems' and 'data_mapper'.

Comment: what is shown when you `p params` just before `my_data = Names.new params`